# Use promises to retrieve all documents from a collection and make a "join" with another collection with Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm struggling to get all documents from collection "clients" and make a join with collection "typeclients" :

Collection "clients" :

id
name
website
idTypeClient

Collection "typeclients" :
id
label

So the database "schema" is quite simple.

Here is the code :

```
async function getListClient()
{

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {

        var tabClient = [];
    
        getDocs(collection(db, "clients")).then(querySnapshot => {

            querySnapshot.forEach(async (clientRef) => {

                // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                // console.log(clientRef.id, " => ", clientRef.data());

                try
                {

                    const typeClientRef = doc(db, "typeclients", clientRef.data().idTypeClient);

                    const typeClientSnap = await getDoc(typeClientRef);

                    var typeClientLabel = "";

                    if(typeClientSnap.exists)
                        typeClientLabel = typeClientSnap.data().label;


                    tabClient.push({id:clientRef.id , nom:clientRef.data().nom , website:clientRef.data().website , typeClientLabel:typeClientLabel});

                    resolve(tabClient);

                }
                catch (e) 
                {
                    console.error("Error fetching document: ", e);
                }

            });

        });
    
    });

  }
```

Sometimes I get all the documents, someone a few, sometimes none. I guess the issue is with promises. Please just don't explain why because I may not understand how to implement the fix, but also fix my code :)

Thanks

Comment: async in a forEach loop doesn't work the way you expect.  It will iterate all of the items before any of the inner async work is complete. If you want tabClient to be populated with all the data in order, you will have to use one of the techniques listed in the duplicate to ensure that all items are handled completely, in order, before you later use tabClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following, using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) should do the trick (untested):

```
async function getListClient() {

  try {
    const tabClient = [];
    const promises = [];
    const clientSnapshots = [];

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "clients"));
    querySnapshot.forEach((clientSnapshot) => {
        const typeClientRef = doc(db, "typeclients", clientSnapshot.data().idTypeClient);
        promises.push(getDoc(typeClientRef));
        clientSnapshots.push(clientSnapshot);
    });

    const typeClientSnapshots = await Promise.all(promises);  // Array, same order than clientSnapshots

    typeClientSnapshots.forEach((typeClientSnapshot, index) => {
      var typeClientLabel = "";
      if (typeClientSnapshot.exists)
        typeClientLabel = typeClientSnapshot.data().label;
      tabClient.push({ id: clientSnapshots[index].id, nom: clientSnapshots[index].data().nom, website: clientSnapshots[index].data().website, typeClientLabel: typeClientLabel });
    })

    return tabClient;
  } catch (error) {
    // ...
  }

}
```

Note that `Promise.all()` returns "a Promise that is asynchronously fulfilled, when all the promises in the given iterable (i.e. our `promises` array) fulfill. The fulfillment value is an array of fulfillment values (i.e. our `typeClientSnapshots` array), **in the order of the promises passed**, regardless of completion order".

This ensures that you can use the `clientSnapshots` Array in the `typeClientSnapshots.forEach()` loop, using the `index` values.

Comment: Merci m'sieur ! It works and it is a masterpiece! Thanks you. This code can be useful to a lot of people.